# How to retrieve particular data from firebase?

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, real-time

[image: I have firebase structure like this]

While retrieving the data I am using this code

```
databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
     for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
       Firebasemodel firebasemodel = data.getValue(Firebasemodel.class);
       firebasemodels.add(firebasemodel);
    }
 }
 @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

}
});`
```

This code snippet which returns the complete data of firebase database.

But I want to retrieve the complete data of particular users. How do I achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try code below:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("notepad-secure/notepad").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Iterator<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshots = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

        while (dataSnapshots.hasNext()) {
            user = dataSnapshotChild.getValue(User.class);
            users_list.add(user);
        }
    }

    @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d("Error", "---" + databaseError.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Model class:

```
public class User {

    public String id;
    public String note;
    public String tittle;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String id, String note, String tittle) {
        this.id= id;
        this.note= note;
        this.tittle= tittle;
    }
}
```

And Declare

```
List<User> users_list;
User user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code for getting all data:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference notepadRef = rootRef.child("notepad-secure").child("notepad");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String id = ds.child("id").getValue(String.class);
            String note = ds.child("note").getValue(String.class);
            String title = ds.child("title").getValue(String.class);
            String user = ds.child("user").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", id + " / " + note + " / " + title + " / " + users);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
notepadRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

And your output will be:

```
-Kono2LMSe... / sadsad / sadsad / NK46X......
```

If you want to retrieve only specific data, please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference notepadRef = rootRef.child("notepad-secure").child("notepad").child("NK46...");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    String id = ds.child("id").getValue(String.class);
    String note = ds.child("note").getValue(String.class);
    String title = ds.child("title").getValue(String.class);
    String user = ds.child("user").getValue(String.class);
    Log.d("TAG", id + " / " + note + " / " + title + " / " + users);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
notepadRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

It will work for sure.

Comment: Edited my answer. I have added `.child("notepad-secure")`. The uotput shoulb be as explained above. Does it work?

Comment: No its not working, Let me give an example, say I have 3 users like A, B, C. A made 3 notes, B made 2 notes, C made 10 notes. So If A has loggedin then I want to retrive the data of A's notes only.